# Is there a 'multimap' implementation in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python, and I am familiar with implementations of [Multimaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) in [other](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html) [languages](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). Does Python have such a data structure built-in, or available in a commonly-used library?

To illustrate what I mean by "multimap":

```
a = multidict()
a[1] = 'a'
a[1] = 'b'
a[2] = 'c'

print(a[1])  # prints: ['a', 'b']
print(a[2])  # prints: ['c']
```

Comment: @ccfenix, I added an example of what I think you wanted.  If this is wrong, please edit to make the example correct.  An example helps people to answer your question; they need to know what you are looking for.

Comment: yah, exactly what i want, thank you steveha!

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576835-multimap-associating-multiple-values-to-a-key/ seems to implement the syntax you are after

Comment: Using `a[1] = 'b'` to mean *append to a[1]* is going to be confusing for people reading or maintaining this code. I would recommend you not do this in Python.

Answer (score 147):

Such a thing is not present in the standard library. You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) though:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> md = defaultdict(list)
>>> md[1].append('a')
>>> md[1].append('b')
>>> md[2].append('c')
>>> md[1]
['a', 'b']
>>> md[2]
['c']
```

(Instead of `list` you may want to use `set`, in which case you'd call `.add` instead of `.append`.)

---

**As an aside**: look at these two lines you wrote:

```
a[1] = 'a'
a[1] = 'b'
```

This seems to indicate that you want the expression `a[1]` to be equal to two distinct values. This is not possible with dictionaries because their keys are unique and each of them is associated with a single value. What you *can* do, however, is extract all values inside the list associated with a given key, one by one. You can use [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#iter) followed by successive calls to [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#next) for that. Or you can just use two loops:

```
>>> for k, v in md.items():
...     for w in v:
...         print("md[%d] = '%s'" % (k, w))
... 
md[1] = 'a'
md[1] = 'b'
md[2] = 'c'
```

Answer (score 9):

Just for future visitors. Currently there is a python implementation of Multimap. It's available via [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultiMap)

Comment: "The defining quality of this project vs others is that values mapped by the same key are not ordered together." How is this different than using `defaultdict(set)`?

Comment: It doesn't say "ordered" at your link, it says "grouped".  So it's not a set because the same element can be inserted twice.  It behaves more like a sorted list, I guess.

Comment: This was last updated in 2011. It appears to be written in Python 2 and it makes some pretty bad design decisions. The worst I saw: `items()` doesn't return all items (only one random value per unique key), and deleting a key basically rewrites the whole dict so it's O(n). I don't think this is production-quality code.

Answer (score 5):

You can take list of tuples and than can sort them as if it was a multimap.

```
listAsMultimap=[]
```

Let's append some elements (tuples):

```
listAsMultimap.append((1,'a'))
listAsMultimap.append((2,'c'))
listAsMultimap.append((3,'d'))
listAsMultimap.append((2,'b'))
listAsMultimap.append((5,'e'))
listAsMultimap.append((4,'d'))
```

Now sort it.

```
listAsMultimap=sorted(listAsMultimap)
```

After printing it you will get:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

That means it is working as a Multimap!

Please note that like multimap here values are also sorted in ascending order if the keys are the same (for key=2, 'b' comes before 'c' although we didn't append them in this order.)

If you want to get them in descending order just change the sorted() function like this:

```
listAsMultimap=sorted(listAsMultimap,reverse=True)
```

And after you will get output like this:

```
[(5, 'e'), (4, 'd'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'a')]
```

Similarly here values are in descending order if the keys are the same.

Comment: This NOT the same as a multimap, where has O(1) costs. The above is O(NlogN).

Comment: @user48956 , I guess you are being confused between unordered_multimap and multimap. Multimap has a complixity of O(NlogN) and NOT O(1). And above implementation is for Multimap and NOT for unordered_multimap which uses hashing to reduce time complexity and has a constant average time complexity on average. Find the differences here: (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) and here: (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/)

Comment: in c++ multimap lookup is O(logN).

Answer (score 3):

There is no multi-map in the Python standard libs currently.

WebOb has a [MultiDict](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/webob/multidict.py.html) class used to represent HTML form values, and it is used by a few Python Web frameworks, so the implementation is battle tested.

Werkzeug also has a [MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/0.6.2/datastructures.html#werkzeug.MultiDict) class, and for the same reason.

Comment: WebOb's implementation just stores (key,value) pairs in an unordered list, so all operations are O(n). Werkzeug's uses a dict of lists so it's relatively efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to write this in Python is with a dict whose elements are each a  `list` or `set`.  As [stephan202 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731971/is-there-multimap-implementation-in-python/1731989#1731989), you can somewhat automate this with a defaultdict, but you don't have to.

In other words I would translate your code to

```
a = dict()
a[1] = ['a', 'b']
a[2] = ['c']

print(a[1])  # prints: ['a', 'b']
print(a[2])  # prints: ['c']
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Because it doesn't look enough like a dict?  I think treating `a[1] = 'b'` as appending to, rather than replacing, `a[1]`, is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think your suggestion doesn't add anything to the discussion, which might explain the negative response.  You certainly can use a dict of keys to lists of values, but this manual implementation is annoying, repetitive, and somewhat error-prone.  A multimap, like [Guava's Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) for Java, is nothing more than a map of lists, but it's tremendously convenient exactly because it hides that implementation.  Your suggestion is accurate, but it lacks any convenience.

Comment: The point I was trying to make, which is not made by the others, is: using a multimap is not Pythonic. The idiomatic way is a dict of sets.

Comment: I like the discussion of pythonic. Coming from Java and Perl I suspect @dimo414's concern has to do with instantiating the list when adding a new key. The answer could have expanded on the what is pythonic in that regard.

Comment: ...went and looked at defaultdict in more detail and like it as a solution. I would guess the downvotes are because you didn't address creating the list that defaultdict does for you.

Answer (score 3):

Stephan202 has the right answer, use `defaultdict`. But if you want something with the interface of C++ STL multimap and much worse performance, you can do this:

```
multimap = []
multimap.append( (3,'a') )
multimap.append( (2,'x') )
multimap.append( (3,'b') )
multimap.sort()
```

Now when you iterate through `multimap`, you'll get pairs like you would in a `std::multimap`. Unfortunately, that means your loop code will start to look as ugly as C++.

```
def multimap_iter(multimap,minkey,maxkey=None):
  maxkey = minkey if (maxkey is None) else maxkey
  for k,v in multimap:
    if k<minkey: continue
    if k>maxkey: break
    yield k,v

# this will print 'a','b'
for k,v in multimap_iter(multimap,3,3):
  print v
```

In summary, `defaultdict` is really cool and leverages the power of python and you should use it.

Answer (score 3):

Or subclass `dict`:

```
class Multimap(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, [value])  # call super method to avoid recursion
        else
            self[key].append(value)
```

Comment: This isn't going to behave exactly like a dict, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict