# how to append a new value to the existing dict key without overwrite

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

The title describes the problem, this is what i tried and this is not giving me expected resoult.. where is the problem?

```
for name in file:              
  if name in list:
    if dict.has_key(param):
      dict[param] = [dict[param],name]
    else:
      dict[param] = name
```

expecting output:

```
dict = {
'param1': ['name11', 'name12', 'name13'],
'param2': ['name21', 'name22', 'name23'],
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, your dictionary is not valid python.

Comment: @msvalkon just forgot the semicolon

Comment: that does not make it valid.

Comment: It actually makes it less valid.

Comment: Try copy pasting your `dict={...}` in to the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append these names to a list. The following is a naive example and might break.

```
for name in file:              
    if name in list:
        if dict.has_key(param):
            dict[param].append(name)
        else:
            dict[param] = [name]
```

Or if you want to be a little cleaner, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This is the pythonic way if you ask me.

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name in file:
    if name in lst: # previously overwrote list()
        d[param].append(name)
```

Please *do not* overwrite the builtin `dict()` or `list()` function with your own variable.

Comment: I thought that append doesn't work with dicts, at least it gave me an error while i was trying this but now it works, maybe because i didn't try to use append after `else` condition

Comment: @Streak the `else` clause wraps `name` in `[]`, thus turning it into a list containing a single element. It's not very pretty, I would use the second solution.

Comment: I'd also add, please *do not* overwrite the builtin `list()` function with your own variable

Comment: For the first answer, you can avoid the `else` and the hack using the `.get` method, but using `defaultdict` is the preferred pythonic way.

Comment: @Javier I feel that's *slightly* hackish as well. I would direct everyone to use the defaultdict, or maybe add an example with `dict.setdefault`.

Comment: @msvalkon totally agree, that is precisely what `defaultdict` was introduced for. I'd only use the get trick if I had to deal with an object that has been defined somewhere else; e.g. if the dict comes as the output from a mongodb query.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a multi map, i.e. a map or dictionary which does not have a key -> value relation but a key -> many values, see:

See [Is there a 'multimap' implementation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731971/is-there-a-multimap-implementation-in-python/4191405)