# Pairing elements in python

Tags: python, dictionary, pairing

I wish to pair up two elements.
I know this can be done by dictionary but the limitation in dictionary is that two key values cant be same.

Example:

```
    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
    4 5
    2 3
    3 4
    3 5
    3 6
    6 7
```

i want something like this:

```
    {1:2,1:3,1:4,4:5,2:3,3:4,3:5,3:6,6:7}
```

But by using dictionary the output generated is :

```
    {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 5, 6: 7}
```

How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with a list of tuples? Or a dictionary where the values are tuples or lists?

Comment: Perhaps  you want an [implementation of a `multimap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731971/is-there-a-multimap-implementation-in-python)?

Comment: Eg, `{'1': ['2', '3', '4'], '4': ['5'], '2': ['3'], '3': ['4', '5', '6'], '6': ['7']}`

Comment: So you want your output to look like a dictionary without being one? Or possibly what a set would output , you could put all those into list items and generate a set I’m assuming,  there are no exact two alike correct ? @pm2ring is that possible to output that style with set?

Comment: Like we have 'pair' in c++(stl), do we have anything similar to that in python?

Comment: It would help if you told us what you want to do with this data structure. And you still didn't say what's wrong with a list of tuples, or the other structures I've suggested.

Comment: i want to iterate over it find the most occurring element in it, will it be efficiently done in the list of tuples that you have generated?

Comment: @maxdean you want the most occurring element? If you said that to begin, you would have got immediate answers that would accomplish this

Comment: It sounds like you want a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Yes i have applied counter already, but my main concern here is , do we have a parallel of pair(stl) in python ?

Comment: @pm2ring now that it’s rephrased it sounds like a duplicate tbh

Comment: The natural way to store a collection of pairs in Python is to use a list of tuples, eg `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (4, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (6, 7)]`. If the first item in a pair is a value and the second is a count, we can feed that to a Counter to get the cumulative counts, resulting in `Counter({3: 15, 1: 9, 6: 7, 4: 5, 2: 3})`

Comment: I don't know C++ (although I do know C). And I don't know what you mean by "stl".

Comment: I think the list of tuples should do the trick , Thank you :')